# For read-only usage do all global variables need to be explicitly imported into local scope?

Tags: python, global

I have read conflicting accounts on whether explicit imports were required for *read only* usage. On all accounts the imports are required for any *mutations* to globals.

Specifically I am annoyed by needing to put `global ...` inside *every* method within a single script for such things as `Enums` that are *always* invariant.  I'd like a program-level setting to just *allow* read-only usage of _globals.

What are the options here?

**Update**  I see what is happening: the `Pycharm` is actually only flagging these when there is a *mutation* happening. It was hard to discover because often enough the first usages of the global variable were read-only : but only further down in a given method were the mutations happening. In the case shown in the screenshot it is the `lastBadgeId`:

[image]

If the mutations in subsequent code in that same method are commented out then the red goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to declare a `global` for a variable which you only read. In a complex program, this may help the reader; but there is no technical necessity. A more useful convention anyway is to use upper case for globals.

Comment: Identifiers with all capital letters are being used for **constants** (which may or may not be global). There is no special capitalization for global variables in the Python standards. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#constants https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#global-variable-names